# nest loops in AngularJS: why different syntaxes?

Tags: angular

I have a table that looks like this:

[image]

The angular code that produces it looks like this:

```
<table id="bt-consequence-table" class="table table-hover table-striped table-condensed">
                  <thead><tr><th>Category</th><th>Description</th></tr>
</thead>
                  <ng-template ngFor let-consequenceGroup [ngForOf]="bowtieDiagram.ConsequenceContainer.BowtieLeafs" let-i="index">
                      <tr [ngClass]="{'selected': selectedConsequence == i, 'bt-table-row': true}"
                          *ngFor="let consequence of consequenceGroup.BowtieLeafObjects; let j = index"
                          [attr.data-index]="i"

(click)="bowtieDiagram.ConsequenceContainer.selectLeafByIndex(i); selectedConsequence = i;">
                          <td>{{consequenceGroup.GroupName}}</td>
                          <td>{{consequence.Description}}</td>
                      </tr>
                  </ng-template>
              </table>
```

Notice that there are two loop in the code above. The outer loop is implemented with this line:

```
<ng-template ngFor let-consequenceGroup [ngForOf]="bowtieDiagram.ConsequenceContainer.BowtieLeafs" let-i="index">
```

The inner loop is implemented with this line:

```
<tr [ngClass]="{'selected': selectedConsequence == i, 'bt-table-row': true}"
                          *ngFor="let consequence of consequenceGroup.BowtieLeafObjects; let j = index"
                          [attr.data-index]="i"

(click)="bowtieDiagram.ConsequenceContainer.selectLeafByIndex(i); selectedConsequence = i;">
```

What I'm wondering is, why does the syntax of the two loops have to be so different?

I tried writing the outer for loop with the same syntax as the inner for loop like so:

```
<ng-template *ngFor="let consequenceGroup of bowtieDiagram.ConsequenceContainer.BowtieLeafs; let i = index">
```

But when I do that, I get an empty table:

[image]

Can someone please tell me why I have to use the incorrect syntax in order to get the outer loop to work?

Comment: the problem is not the ngFor syntax but ng-template. replace ng-template by ng-container and ideally only use this syntax *ngFor="let bla of blabla" rather than the long version which was an experimental one

Comment: Thanks Mehdi, that worked perfectly.